# Sphinx link to static file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have an RST document like this in  `source/chapter1/section1/intro.rst`:

```
Test Static Path:
=================

{{ pathto('_static/_resources/intro-01_v3.mp4') }}


What I Need:
============

.. raw:: html

   <video width="100%" height="540" controls>
      <source src="{{ pathto('_static/_resources/intro-01_v3.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
```

But the output of sphinx `make html` command for this block doesn't run the [pathto function](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#pathto) and both **video source** and **test section** will be `{{ pathto('_static/_resources/intro-01_v3.mp4') }}` itself.

I want to show the video inside the browser, so I can't use [:download:](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-download) or [.. image::](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images).

Is there a way to get a link/path to a file in `_static` directory?

I need something to **GENERATE** `../../_static/_resources/intro-01_v3.mp4`.

Comment: The `raw` directive does not interpret reST or MyST syntax. It is well-named. Instead use a root-relative URL: `<source src="/_static/_resources/intro-01_v3.mp4" blah blah blah>`

Comment: the page is not served on root directory of web server, so `/_static/_resources/intro-01_v3.mp4` is not working.

Comment: I have tested `pathto` outside of raw directive, that does not work too.

Comment: Sphinx does not automatically process Jinja templates that occur in .rst files. I think you'll need something like https://www.ericholscher.com/blog/2016/jul/25/integrating-jinja-rst-sphinx/ or https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-jinja/.

Comment: If that path does not work, then you have not configured [`html_static_path` in `conf.py`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651) in comments, by configuring [sphinx-jinja](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-jinja/) and using `.. jinja::` directive, it will render `pathto`.