# Accessing source filename in sphinx/restructured text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to add the following line to my conf.py file for Sphinx documentation, which apparently is valid for [nbsphinx](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.7/prolog-and-epilog.html) but isn't working for Sphinx 4.0.2.

```
rst_epilog = r"""
{% set docname = env.doc2path(env.docname, base=None) %}

.. tip:: this is {{ docname }}
"""
```

**Update**

Based upon suggestions made in the comments, I have reviewed [this blog entry](https://www.ericholscher.com/blog/2016/jul/25/integrating-jinja-rst-sphinx/) describing integration of Rst and Jinja in Sphinx and attempted to incorporate [this tutorial information](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html) about creating a custom extension.

My approach was to follow the tutorial for including directories and modifying `conf.py` while using the module verbatim from the blog for my extension.

Ultimately, my desired use is still not functioning properly.  I can confirm that Sphinx knows of my extension by including typos in the module (which causes `make` to fail) or by changing the extension to do nothing (i.e. commenting out the last line of the `rstjinja` function, so the extension does nothing except burn CPU cycles).

Comment: Please include a stacktrace or error message.

Comment: @StevePiercy no error message - Sphinx renders the line beginning with `{%` as plaintext and the `.. tip::` line as a restructured text directive.  In the latter case `{{ docname }}` remains in the output.

Comment: In the linked example, they use `nbsphinx_epilog`, not `rst_epilog`.

Comment: @StevePiercy correct, nbsphinx is a sphinx extension for parsing Jupyter notebooks.  Since I am not using these notebooks, I did not want to install the extension and am looking for a way to include this functionality with sphinx alone, if possible.

Comment: Sphinx does use Jinja templates, but templates in .rst files or snippets such as `rst_epilog` are not recognized automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68884117/407651.